# Query params for nested objects with python requests module like QS.stringify

Tags: python, python-requests, query-string, strapi

When creating a Strapi client in Python using the requests module I came across a problem.

When using the params argument for the `requests.get` method with a nested dictionary it doesn't translate to a querystring like the npm package [`qs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) does.

I wanted a `qs.stringify` in python but found the answer nowhere on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I found this package:
https://github.com/cine-io/nested-query-string

```py
   def _get(self, path, params=None, **kwargs):
        url = self.__construct_url(path)
        headers = self.__get_request_headers()

        if params is not None:
            #see line here!!
            from nested_query_string import NestedQueryString
            params = NestedQueryString.encode(params)
            
        response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers, **kwargs)
        assert response.status_code == 200
        return self.__parse_strapi_response(response)
```